# Unable to install the VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have installed the vc14 build tools but I could only get these tools: ARM cross tools, x86 native tools, x86 x64 cross tools. I've been told to install the Visual Studio community edition but nothing changed, I still only get those tools.

When I call `vcvarsall.bat amd64` I'm getting the error: `The specified configuration type is missing. The tools for the configuration might not be installed.`

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate (64bit) and I should be able to compile x64 natively. Perhaps I need a newer OS? Or I need a paid Visual Studio version?